# Use local resources in WKWebview

Tags: uiwebview, nsurlrequest, wkwebview, nsurlprotocol

How do I make WKWebview use local .js, .css and/or local image files, in place of remote files, in order to make the web page load faster.
Also, I noticed NSURLProtocol methods (when implemented through register class) do not get called when WKNavigationDelegate methods are implemented, any idea on why?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After going through a lot of documentation, I realized/learnt that I'll not be able to track URLs if I use WKWebviews. I have to resort to UIWebView for the moment.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot track URLs using WKWebView? Take a look at [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/)

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 9 API there is a new method for loading local resource

> /*! @abstract Navigates to the requested file URL on the filesystem.
>        @param URL The file URL to which to navigate.
>        @param readAccessURL The URL to allow read access to.
>        @discussion If readAccessURL references a single file, only that file may be loaded by WebKit.
>        If readAccessURL references a directory, files inside that file may be loaded by WebKit.
>        @result A new navigation for the given file URL.
>        */

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func loadFileURL(URL: NSURL, allowingReadAccessToURL readAccessURL: NSURL) -> WKNavigation?
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I will need the solution to work in ios7 & 8, per requirement :(

Comment: The question is about using cached css/jss assets to speed up navigation for remote websites.

This answer is instead about navigating to a local webpage on device.